# After override table name create not working

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.6

After overriding table name on **__construct**, it is not created as per expectation. it is stored the only default value only.

**Controller: "TestMeController"**

```
use App\TestMe;
use Illuminate\Http\Request; 
use Log;

class TestMeController extends Controller
{
    public function setCreateData() {

        config(['app.temp_db' => "new_test_me"]);
        $test_me_data = ["data" => "new table data"];
        $data = TestMe::create( $test_me_data );

        dd($data);
    }
}
```

**Model: "TestMe"**

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class TestMe extends Model
{

    protected $table = "test_me";

    protected $guarded = ['id']; 

    protected $connection = "mysql";

    public function __construct() {


        if( config('app.temp_db') != "") {
            $this->table = config('app.temp_db');
        }  

    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
.....
#original: array:3 [
    "updated_at" => "2020-01-06 13:34:18"
    "created_at" => "2020-01-06 13:34:18"
    "id" => 100
]
.....
```

it is added only default value, I have to try to get Exception, But there is no exception on it.

Comment: do u have new_test_me table?

Comment: yes I have *new_test_me* table.

Comment: so it will insert into `new_test_me` table without error

Comment: yes, but the default value like id, updated_at, created_at not value that i have to add as data on create()

Comment: no, you don't need to do it,`id` is your auto increment primary key, when you create the object. it will increase, and the `created_at` and `updated_at` will automatically set with current_time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just need to pass **$attributes** on `construct`

**Model: "TestMe"**

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class TestMe extends Model
{

    protected $table = "test_me";

    protected $guarded = ['id']; 

    protected $connection = "mysql";

    public function __construct(array $attributes = []) {  

        parent::__construct($attributes);


        if( config('app.temp_db') != "") {
            $this->table = config('app.temp_db');
        }  

    }
}
```

OUTPUT

```
.....
#original: array:3 [
    "updated_at" => "2020-01-06 13:34:18"
    "created_at" => "2020-01-06 13:34:18"
    "id" => 100
    "data" => "new table data"
]
.....
```